# Image not dropping into dropbox correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, coverflow

Hey guys I'm using a drag and drop feature to basically drop and image from the list into a drop box that will trigger some kind of an even.  But when I drag my image and drop it it just duplicates on top, instead of down in the drop box.

(*edited*: the jquery coverscroll plugin homepage: http://slobodan.99k.org/plugins/coverscroll.html)

For the life of me I can't figure out why its doing this.  I'm using external script that I downloaded to add the sliding image effect and here is my code:

### CSS

```
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#container2 {
    width:850px;
    height:200px;
    margin-left:25px;
}
#container2 img, #container2 .item {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #777;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #777;
}
#dragBox {
    width:336px;
    height:221px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

### script

- **Tag**

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.coverscroll.min.js"></script>
  ```
- **javascript**

  ```
  function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      var theNode = document.getElementById(data);
      var nodeCopy = theNode.cloneNode(true);
      ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
      if (data == "drag1") {
          foodOne();
      }
      if (data == "drag2") {
          foodTwo();
      }
      ev.target.removeChild(nodeCopy);
  }

  function foodOne() {
      alert("You choose Food One");
  }

  function foodTwo() {
      alert("You choose Food Two");
  }
  ```

### HTML

```
<div id="container2">
    <img id="drag1" src="foodOne.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"
    width="336" height="221">
    <img id="drag2" src="foodTwo.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"
    width="336" height="221">
    <img id="drag1" src="foodThree.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"
    width="336" height="221">
    <img id="drag2" src="foodFour.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"
    width="336" height="221">
</div>
<script>
    $('#container2').coverscroll();
</script>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div div align="center">
    <div id="dragBox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
```

If anyone can help out with this it would be awesome.

Here is what it looks like before I do actual drag and drop:

[image: IMG 1]

And after I drop the image into the box:

[image: IMG 2]